# symlink protocol error when setting up storage:link on vagrant homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, symlink, homestead, vagrant-windows

I am attempting to set up a laravel based backpack pro project environment on homestead vagrant however I am stumped at this issue `Script php artisan storage:link --quiet handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1 symlink():protocol error`

[image]

Attempted solution

1. Run git bash as administrator before vagrant ssh-ing
2. manually calling php artisan storage:link
3. checked the permission of the storage folder where it is `drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant      0 Jan 22 07:22 storage`

Comment: as the vagrant tag states: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved by following the steps as mentioned below

- `php artisan config:clear`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan view:clear`
- exit vagrant && close git bash terminal
- Reopen git bash as admin
- cd to vagrant folder
- `vagrant up`
- `vagrant ssh`
- cd to project terminal
- `php artisan storage:link`